# Smart Card Reader on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lts, smartcard

I'm struggling with this bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1972725. Can anyone help with this? Any comment, testing, fix, ... is welcome.

Comment: Looking at your comments on the bug report, seems like you suspect snap as a possible cause. This seems doubtful, since hardware compatibility is provided by the Linux kernel, not by snapd. The description resembles a typical kernel *reversion*. Nevertheless, feel free to test your card-reader with a non-snap browser and see it it works any better, so you can confirm or rule out snapd as the culprit. Who knows? Maybe you are right.

Answer (score 5):

Run these two commands:

```
sudo systemctl start pcscd
sudo systemctl enable pcscd
```

The first starts a service that is necessary for the card to work, the other one ensures it will be running on startup next boot. Source comment #14 here: [https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701636#12](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701636#12%C2%A0)

Comment: Thanks! This saved me on Ubuntu Unity 22.10. I really need this, so I was about to change distro, when I saw your answer here and decided to give it a shot first -- and it works. No need to change distro for this, any more.
The only difference is that I used "start pcscd.service" and "enable pcscd.socket", as suggested by autofinish in my terminal. Works the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced this as well. My temporary solution was to remove the snap package and force Ubuntu to use the ppa/deb package. Note: I wasn't the one that came up with this, I found it here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

followed by this all in one block

```
echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

then

```
sudo snap remove firefox && sudo apt install firefox
```

and this is to try to keep the snap from overwriting the deb

```
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
```

Comment: Did installing Firefox from snap actually solve the issue?